# How can i implement beacon device tap in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, ibeacon, flutter-packages

I am working on a Flutter project where I need to implement functionality that listens for clicks on beacon devices. I am using Flutter for the mobile app development, and I have integrated beacon devices into my project using the flutter_blue package for Bluetooth communication.

I have already implemented beacon detection using the flutter_blue package, but I need help with the code that listens for beacon device clicks.
Any guidance on how to structure the code or examples of similar implementations would be greatly appreciated.
Note: I am specifically looking for Flutter code examples and explanations on how to handle beacon device clicks within my Flutter app.

Requirements :
1.I want to detect when a user clicks on a specific beacon device.
2.The app should continuously scan for nearby beacon devices.

Comment: Not all clickable beacons behave the same -- their behavior depends on the manufacturer.  What do your beacons do differently when the button is clicked?  Also, you say "I have already implemented beacon detection using the flutter_blue package". Can you please show your detection code?  This way we can tell you what you need to change in the code you have already.

Comment: hello @davidgyoung ,
i used below example :
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/example